# To create generic method for various User defined class in java

Tags: java

I am trying to achieve the following:
I have this method

```
public String methodName(Userdefinedclass.class,Userdefinedclass obj)
{

//some code 
.........
method(Userdefinedclass.class);
method2(obj);

}
```

I want to generalise this method.

The challenge is that the argument here is user defined, i.e it can change. So please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public <T> String methodName(Class<T> c, T obj) 
{
    method1(c);
    method2(obj);

    return "some string";
}

void method1(Class c) 
{
   // Some stuff.
}
```

Comment: +1 previous solution was better if user wants to pass two different paramerters like : `Userdefinedclass1.class,Userdefinedclass obj`

Comment: thanks for the reply if i have to call this function  is this the syntax  (eg:if Animal is my class)                                                              methodName(Animal,Animal anim)

Answer (score 1):

Generics is type erasure so you cannot have .class of Generic type. That is becaue generics are erased in this case to `Object` type. Hence `T.class' wont work

So instead use `Class<T>` to get the class and then work along

Answer (score 1):

This keeps your method signature intact:

```
public <T> String  methodName(Class<T> c, T obj)
{
   method(c);
   method2(obj);
}
```

but i would use ivanovic's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generalize the parameters used in the function you can create an empty interface and force the userDefinedClass to implement it..  Or You can use T for achiving this